# Calculate the sum of each possible continuous combination of a integer

Tags: python, c, algorithm, math

Let's say I have a number for example 12345.
I want to calculate the sum each of all possible combinations for this number without changing the order of the digits, as followed:

```
12345
1234+5
123+45
123+4+5
12+345
12+34+5
12+3+45
12+3+4+5
1+2345
1+234+5
1+23+45
1+23+4+5
1+2+345
1+2+34+5
1+2+3+45
1+2+3+4+5
```

I am trying to find a way by doing multiple divisions (div and mod) and also using a for loop with 10^N step where N=[1,2,..,integer length].
The only thing I found is this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031327/all-possible-ways-to-split-a-number

I have tried several modifications in a C and a Python script with no success.

The code I tried is the following code using C but this only breaks the number into different digits:

```
    int break_digits(int n) {
        int remain;
        int sum = 0;
        int original_number = n;
        while (n != 0) {
            remain= n % 10;
            sum+=remain;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return  sum;
    }
```

In Python I have found this code here https://www.techiedelight.com/break-string-non-overlapping-substrings/

```
    OPEN_BRACKET = '{'
    CLOSED_BRACKET = '}'
    EMPTY_STRING = ''
     
    # Function to break a string into all possible combinations of
    # non-overlapping substrings enclosed within parenthesis
    def recur(s, i=0, out=EMPTY_STRING):
        if i == len(s):
            print(out)
     
        # consider each substring S[i, j]
        for j in reversed(range(i, len(s))):
            substr = OPEN_BRACKET + s[i:j+1] + CLOSED_BRACKET
     
            # append the substring to the result and recur with an index of the
            # next character to be processed and the result string
            recur(s, j + 1, out + substr)
     
     
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        s = 'ABCD'    # input string
        recur(s)
```

I am still working on it in order to make it for numbers.
The main task is to create a function that you can give a number and returns the sum of all available continuous combinations.
Does anyone have a thought or hint so I can change the code?

Comment: So, do you want a math answer or programming answer? Because if you want a math formula then this question is off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code would be preferable. I asked for the math formula in case someone knows it and does not have the time to code it.

Comment: You are missing the longest combination. What do you want: the sum of all such combinations, or the list of the sums?

Comment: For an N-digit number you have 2^(N-1) places to put a '+' sign or not. That determines the number of combinations.

Comment: Hi @lastchance. Is this 1+2+3+4+5 not the longest? I want to the sum of each combination. I will do some other calculations then which are out of scope and then discard the sum. I don't want to store it somewhere. Also I think that the formula 2^(N-1) does not give the correct answer. For example for 1234 the combinations are 2 but 2^(4-1) gives  9

Comment: Generally the way you extract digits from a number is using division `/` and modulo `%` operators. Number modulo 10 gives you the least significant digit, number div 10 gives you everything but the lowest digit. You'll probably be using that in your solution.

Comment: @stewas, the biggest number is just 12345 and you've ignored it.

Comment: @lastchance you are right on that. Missed the longest.

Comment: @Verpous hello. I have tried this a lot and probably this is the way of doing it. But still I haven't found and efficient way to use all combinations.

Comment: There is no efficient way to do what you want to do. There are 2^(N-1) possible combinations, that's a nightmare in computer science. Maybe the efficiency comes from the second half of the problem you aren't telling us, where what you want to do with these sums can be achieved quicker without actually calculating all of them.

Comment: One way to do it is this: you have n-1 places you can place that `+` sign, so think of it as a set of all the possible places you can put it. Each combination is a subset of that. From here you can read online about ways to iterate over all possible subets of a set.

Comment: If you just need the sum of all the sums (as the title seems to say), then you can do it more efficiently than O(2^(n-1)). For example, it can be done in O(n^2) by using combinatorics to calculate how many times each substring participates in the sum.

Comment: @stewas "I have tried several modifications in a python script with no success. " --> post your best one.

Comment: It's actually an interesting question, you can solve by generating a powerset of the split points, then summing. I have a python implementation if the question gets reopened / asked with more focus.

Comment: I have a solution (small modification of the mentioned post), will post it on reopening.

Comment: There IS a "formulaic" way to do this problem (that doesn't including identifying all combinations, fortunately). I recommend the question be reopened.

Comment: Hello again. Thank you all for your answers. I have changed the post and sent it for review in order to be reopened. I believe that I should focus on permutations with repetition

Comment: What's the actual desired result? Printing that block of text from `12345` to `1+2+3+4+5`? Or *calculating* those sums (like 15 for the latter)? Returning a list of them instead of printing? Returning a single number, like your `break_digits` function suggests?

Comment: Hello @KellyBundy. Thank toy for your message. I want to calculate the sums in order to use them in another part of code. So the best option is to return each sum but I believe that this is not the scope here. The result can be used as needed. The scope is the formula to do that. If single printing was needed then you can easily convert into string and the work there is much easier.

Comment: Your post still says you want “the sum of all combinations”. That is one sum. But your comments suggest you want the sum for **each** combination. That is more than one sum. You need to edit the post to be clear about what you want. And, if you want more than one, you need to say whether you want a function that returns one sum at a time (so some sort of state management needs to be included in arguments to the function) or you want a function that returns a list of the sums (as in an array) or you want a function that prints the sums or something else.

Comment: @EricPostpischil both are valid points and thank you for sharing. I have edited the post a bit but I will edit it soon in order to include a part of code that I have also tried. The concept is to return the sum of each combination. That's why I believe that it should be done with permutations with repetition.

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a single sum, the "sum of all sums". You can solve this problem much more efficiently if you approach it from a different angle. Don't compute each sum and then combine them. Figure out how many times each substring is going to appear in the final sum, and add to your running total that substring times the number of appearances it should have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is still unclear as to whether you want (1) a collection of the possible sums found systematically, or (2) the grand sum of all these.

This answer addresses (1); you could always sum them up to get (2). However, there are much faster ways to do (2) directly by counting the number of arrangements contain a particular contribution from each digit (e.g., 3 could contribute 3, 30 or 300 in your example 12345).

Anyway, interpretation (1). You want the sum of each particular breakdown.

Consider your example 12345. With 5 digits there are 5-1=4 internal positions where you could choose to put a plus or not. You could represent this set of choices by a binary code: for example, "1010" would correspond to 1+23+45" (i.e. you put a + after the 1 and the 3, but not after the 2 and the 4).

So, all you need to do is cycle through the binary representations

"0000", "0001", "0010", ...., "1111"

and set up the relevant sums. This is done below by the binary representations of integers. Obviously you don't need to output the binary representation as well as the sum at the end, but it helps to show what is going on.

If you want something else ... you'll have to clarify your post!

```
N = int( input( "Input a positive number: " ) )

# Get digits (in left-to-right order)
digits = []
while N > 0:
    digits.append( N % 10 )
    N = N // 10
digits.reverse()

numPlus = len( digits ) - 1
for plusPositions in range( 0, 1 << numPlus ):
    # Get binary position of where to place + signs
    str = f"{plusPositions:0{numPlus}b}"

    # Form the sum described by these positions
    current = digits[0]
    sum = 0
    for b, d in zip( str, digits[1:] ):
        if b == '0':
            current = 10 * current + d
        else:
            sum += current
            current = d
    sum += current
    print( str, " ---> ", sum )
```

Output:

```
Input a positive number: 12345
0000  --->  12345
0001  --->  1239
0010  --->  168
0011  --->  132
0100  --->  357
0101  --->  51
0110  --->  60
0111  --->  24
1000  --->  2346
1001  --->  240
1010  --->  69
1011  --->  33
1100  --->  348
1101  --->  42
1110  --->  51
1111  --->  15
```

Answer (score 2):

Go through the digits, keeping track of the overall sum and the current value (and the remaining digits), either add the current digit to the current value or make it start a new value.

Recursive:

```py
def f(s, c, *D):
  if D:
    d, *D = D
    return f(s, c*10+d, *D) + f(s+c, d, *D)
  return [s+c]
print(f(0, *map(int, str(12345))))
```

Iterative:

```
d, *D = map(int, str(12345))
S = [(0, d)]
for d in D:
  S = [t for s, c in S for t in [(s, c*10+d), (s+c, d)]]
print(*map(sum, S))
```

Alternatively, using itertools to put nothing or plus signs between the digits and evaluate:

```
from itertools import product

s = str(12345)
a = [None] * (2*len(s) - 1)
a[::2] = s
for a[1::2] in product(['', '+'], repeat=len(s)-1):
  print(eval(''.join(a)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZExboQwEEWV1qf4HTaYaNkkUoS0HXUaSkSBFlvxCmxkTKScJc02SZkD5TSxDWSbuMH__xnmyfPxNb27V6Ov18_Fyfz55-67FxKSzhxnjrRiJQGURBW-QB88nFBFZYVbrN6q0-KQxZghC1bm-1dN_iob77Zksko7KunBp2M3Ua84ZmdpcXx4fGL-EEL2Sf8VkNoHTejvWUukseih9MoYI4dgBqrg11G5cG1uqIxjg2TtzhRx5mXkqCOEtGaEcsI6Y4YZapyMdZis6ZezI2T2s25YpAujX4wWLVLQYzoITWeGHIXPmrI8tqE-8nZNEbVH2v5GmyThSLKk5f61JtG509qfF3EHK6B46waaJPcXozTt_Euta9u2t2_xFw)

Answer (score 1):

For a number with ***N*** digits, there are ***N-1*** places where you can break the number so ***2<sup>N-1</sup>*** different ways to break the number into chunks of adjacent digits.

Here is some C code to print all such combinations and compute the sum of all these chunks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_DIGITS  20

long long print_sum(long long number, long long bits) {
    long long n = number;
    long long sum = 0;
    long long div = 1;
    long long chunk[MAX_DIGITS];
    int pos = MAX_DIGITS;

    while (bits) {
        div *= 10;
        if (bits & 1) {
            sum += chunk[--pos] = n % div;
            n /= div;
            div = 1;
        }
        bits >>= 1;
    }
    sum += n;
    printf("%lld", n);
    while (pos < MAX_DIGITS)
        printf("+%lld", chunk[pos++]);
    printf(" = %lld\n", sum);
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long long number = 12345;
    long long total = 0;
    long long max = 1;

    if (argc > 1)
        number = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);

    for (long long n = number; n > 9; n /= 10)
        max <<= 1;

    for (long long i = 0; i < max; i++)
        total += print_sum(number, i);

    printf("total = %lld\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12345 = 12345
1234+5 = 1239
123+45 = 168
123+4+5 = 132
12+345 = 357
12+34+5 = 51
12+3+45 = 60
12+3+4+5 = 24
1+2345 = 2346
1+234+5 = 240
1+23+45 = 69
1+23+4+5 = 33
1+2+345 = 348
1+2+34+5 = 42
1+2+3+45 = 51
1+2+3+4+5 = 15
total = 17520
```